# How to do a pull request if i did the changes on a cloned repository?

Tags: git, fork, pull-request, cloning

I am a newbie to git and i made the mistake of cloning a repository and added some changes on different branches to that one. How can i possibly do a pull request to the original repository considering that i have multiple branches that i have to do a pull request to?

Comment: Are you using github for pull requests ?

Comment: Not only for pull requests @DeepakPatankar

Answer (score 1):

Commit and push your code to repo:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some commit message"
git push origin your_branch_name
```

Create a pull request by clicking on `Pull Request tab`
Click on create pull request.

Verify your changes and merge the Pull Request.